# Email client for large IMAP folders ie uses Server side search etc

Tags: windows, macos, thunderbird, imap, email-client

I'm looking for a mail client that supports handling rather large IMAP folders and that can ignore notifications for specific subfolders.

I'm an old Mozilla Mail user and obviously I migrated to Thunderbird a long time ago. However, the lack of response to filed "bug reports"/requests about re-enabling server side search instead of local search in combination with a complete lack of support for disabling notifications for specific (sub)folders has made me go for a hunt.

Does anyone know any decent client for Windows and OS X for this? I am actually considering making a branch of Thunderbird or try to patch up old Mozilla Mail again. This is crazy. ;-)

Comment: Ok there goes my entire rep for a bounty, pleease! ;)

Comment: I don't use these these features, but it's possible Eudora OSE supports them. It claims it can do server-side searches. As for the notification thing, I'm not sure. Maybe using the filters and setting up custom notifications per-folder? https://wiki.mozilla.org/Eudora_OSE

Comment: As far as I know there is a "Run search on server" option in Thunderbird 3. Do you mean that it doesn't work ? Also, notification should work for folders where you have explicitly enabled checking for new messages.

Comment: @harrymc I've tried all kind of search functions in thunderbird. Nowadays it's all on client side and thunderbird basically hangs. I want notification but only on the important mailboxes.

Comment: Some email servers have a lousy implementation of server-side search. Have you tried more than one such server?

Comment: @harrymc it has nothing to do with the server iam afraid. it's the same server running for years and thunderbird just dropped support for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Thunderbird is still said to be the best IMAP client around, and version 3 is supposed to have improved IMAP support.

There have been some IMAP changes in TB3, which are summarized in
[Thunderbird 3.0 - New Features and Changes IMAP Accounts](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Thunderbird_3.0_-_New_Features_and_Changes#IMAP_Accounts).

The most significant change was that when updating from 2.0 or an older version, all IMAP accounts are marked for offline use, which might slow TB down but avoids a problem when printing messages with attachments. If this problem doesn't concern you, you may undo the change for improved performance.

Your problem might also have been caused by a bad upgrade to TB3. You could try to uninstall TB3, clean-out the installation folder and install again.

I have searched the [Thunderbird Support forums](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewforum.php?f=39&sid=7e2d29e764c37d61eef257c5d3a54eef) and have not found any significant reports about problems with IMAP, and recent questions seemed to have been well-answered. So if the above didn't help, I would suggest to try the forums again.

If the problem is still unsolved, but did not occur in TB2, I would suggest returning to it, as it is still probably the best client you could find. You could also try the email clients of Windows and OS X (but I personally would still prefer TB).

Answer (score 0):

The best client for IMAP support, and that can handle large IMAP mailboxes, is Mulberry: https://mulberrymail.com/.

It's a bit old now, but still very good.